# Slowmode command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

When I type `;sm`, my bot responds with: *"You need to specify a time in seconds"* <-- Thats okay.

But when I type `;sm [time]`, it still responds with: *"You need to specify a time in seconds."*, but it should set the rate limit and tell me that *"Slowmode is now [time]s"*.

Here's my code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message) => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) 
        return message.channel.send("You need `MANAGE_MESSAGES` permission to execute this command.");
    const messageArray = message.content.split(' ');
    const args = messageArray.slice(1);

    if (!args[1] == null) {
        message.channel.setRateLimitPerUser(args[0])
        message.channel.send(`Slowmode is now ${args[0]}s`)
    }
    if (args[1] == null) {
        return message.channel.send("You need to specify time in seconds!")
    };
};

module.exports.config = {
    name: "sm",
    aliases: []
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you understand what your variables are. If you type a command like `!sm 10`, your `messageArray` will be an array like `['!sm', '10']` and your `args` will be an array like `['10']`.

When you slice the array (`messageArray.slice(1)`), you remove the first element. So if you want to check the first argument after the command you should check `args[0]`, not `args[1]`.

Second, when you check `!args[1] == null` you're converting `args[1]` to a boolean. If you check if a boolean is `null`, it will always return `false`, so you'll never execute `setRateLimitPerUser`.

```js
console.log(true == null)  // => false
console.log(false == null) // => false
```

You can instead check if the argument is null. If it is, you can return early. This way you don't need another if or else if statement. Even better, you could check if the argument is a not a number using [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).

```js
module.exports.run = async (bot, message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES'))
    return message.channel.send(
      'You need `MANAGE_MESSAGES` permission to execute this command.',
    );
  const messageArray = message.content.split(' ');
  const args = messageArray.slice(1);
  const seconds = args[0];
  const MAX_SECONDS = 21600;

  if (isNaN(seconds)) {
    return message.channel.send('You need to specify time in seconds!');
  }

  if (seconds > MAX_SECONDS) {
    return message.channel.send(
      `The maximum number of seconds is ${MAX_SECONDS}.`,
    );
  }

  try {
    await message.channel.setRateLimitPerUser(seconds);
    message.channel.send(`Slowmode is now ${seconds}s`);
  } catch (error) {
    message.channel.send('Oops, there is a problem with that command');
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, Thanks it works. I have another question. Would it be possible to set max number that can be slowmode is: 86400 or basically one day? thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. I've just updated my answer with the max number. I think the maximum Discord allows is 6 hours though, which is 21600 seconds.